# LDAP3 Module getting more than 1000 results or alternatives

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap3

```
# import class and constants
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, SUBTREE

# define the server
s = Server(host='xyz', port=xxxx, use_ssl=True, get_info='ALL')
c = Connection(s, auto_bind='NONE', version=3, authentication='ANONYMOUS', client_strategy='SYNC', auto_referrals=True, check_names=True, read_only=False, lazy=False, raise_exceptions=False)

c.bind()
results = c.extend.standard.paged_search(
    search_base = 'Ou=XYZ,dc=org,dc=com',
    search_filter = '(AppID=*)',
    search_scope = SUBTREE,
    get_operational_attributes=True,
    attributes=['*'],
    generator=True,
    paged_size=None
)
i=0

for entries in results:
    print(entries)
    i+=1
print(i)
```

I am trying to connect to a server on a specific port and doing an ANONYMOUS SSL authentication. I have written the above script to get the results for "AppID=*".  I am only able to print 1000 records and after that I run into the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Fetch data.py", line 43,
>   in 
>       for entries in results:   File "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ldap3\extend\standard\PagedSearch.py",
>   line 75, in paged_search_generator
>       raise LDAPOperationResult(result=result['result'], description=result['description'], dn=result['dn'],
>   message=result['message'], response_type=result['type'])
>   ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPSizeLimitExceededResult:
>   LDAPSizeLimitExceededResult - 4 - sizeLimitExceeded - None - None -
>   searchResDone - None

I have tried the solutions provided [Conquering Active Directory's 1000 record limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505403/conquering-active-directorys-1000-record-limit)

I have tried going through the document [LDAP3 Docs](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/searches.html)  but no success. Is there a way to read complete output. (I imagine there are more than 5k records)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your code would generate a generator object.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SUBTREE
import ldap3
total_entries = 0
# define the server
s = Server(host='xyz', port=xxxx, use_ssl=True, get_info=ldap3.NONE)
c = Connection(s,authentication='ANONYMOUS') 
# subtitute your filter here 
filter = '(&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName=))'
entry_generator = c.extend.standard.paged_search(search_base = 'Ou=XYZ,dc=org,dc=com',
                                                 search_filter = filter,
                                                 search_scope = SUBTREE,
                                                 get_operational_attributes=True,
                                                 attributes = ['*'],
                                                 paged_size = 1000,
                                                 generator=True)
for entry in entry_generator:
    total_entries += 1
    print(entry['dn'], entry['attributes'])
print('Total entries retrieved:', total_entries)
```

This should give you all the details that you need.
Reference [ldap3 documents](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searches.html#simple-paged-search).

Comment: I tried something similar that worked . You have answered my question. Thank you! :D